# Unable to display image in avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

```xml
<Image Name="ImageDisplay" 
               Source="{Binding CurrentImage}"
               Grid.Column="1"/>
```

```cs
public class NewWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Bitmap CurrentImage = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Assets\LOGO.png"));
    }
```

```cs
public NewWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new NewWindowViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
#if DEBUG
            this.AttachDevTools();
#endif
        }
```

Image is not displayed, output returns error: `[Binding] Error in binding to 'Avalonia.Controls.Image'.'Source': 'Could not find a matching property accessor for 'CurrentImage' on 'RandomProject.ViewModels.NewWindowViewModel''`

Everything should be working fine, except it doesn't. I'm new to Avalonia, I wanted to free myself from being limited only to Windows, but my first impressions are not exactly good.

There is official documentation here https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/image, but its FULL of errors. Not exactly helpful when your project won't even build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a getter method for this property also.

```
public Bitmap getCurrentImage()
{
    return CurrentImage;
}
```